# Eclipse Debug/Run On Server

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat

I've been developing a Java web application for my internship with Eclipse and all has been going well until this afternoon.

Randomly one of the times when I chose to debug on server (Apache Tomcat v7) it took 30 seconds as opposed to the usual 3-5 seconds. I undid my changes to no avail thinking that I had just done something really inefficiently(I had changed all the structures of my Hibernate mappings) and it still didn't resolve the issue. I also tried removing and re-adding the server several times.

Though, the funny thing is when I choose run on server it still runs it in like 3-5 seconds.

Thanks in advance for whatever help anyone can offer.

Comment: With further research I found online other people who had this issue and clearing all breakpoints in my project seemed to resolve this.

Comment: yes, you may also uncheck them from the breakpoints section in case you need to remove them temporarily

Comment: Also read this ....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473503/what-are-the-best-general-practice-debugging-tricks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing all your previous debug threads, or debug in no breakpoint mode there are cases when debug threads goes in sleep.It is not a in efficient code case. Try closing your debug logs, it also consumes some seconds to print all debug logs on console.
Moreover,you may also try to delete your logs as it takes time to write on heavy log files as compared to the smaller files.